# NAT Configutation

Tags: networking, nat, gaming

I play Warface and when I contacted the technical support they told me this:

> According to the diagnostic files, your Internet Provider is using NAT making the route of the connection. We cannot guarantee that game client will work properly if NAT is used on the provider's side of the connection.

So is there any solution for this? Can I disable my NAT and continue using the Internet through a specific program or something? Or cannot I and should I forget about this game?

Answer (score 1):

Read the message carefully:

> According to the diagnostic files, your **Internet provider is using NAT** making the route of the connection. We cannot guarantee that game client will work properly if NAT is used on the **provider's side** of the connection

This is not talking about your router being setup for NAT (which is so common these days any service pretty much has to support it), but about your ISP implementing something called *carrier-grade NAT*.

If the IP you get from your ISP is a 192.168.X.X or other private-range IP, then your ISP uses CGNAT.  Cellular ISPs are going to be more likely to  do this than others.

You can't do anything on your end to change this, you would have to talk to your ISP and see if you can get a real, public IP from them.  Another solution is to use a VPN such as Hamachi - everyone who wants to play will need to be on the same Hamachi network.  I haven't used the service before but I do know it is used to allow gamers to connect to each other easily.

Comment: Worth pointing out that any technical problems with Warface caused by being behind a ISP provided NAT likely can be solved by just using any commercial VPN in general.  This is because all traffic between you and Warface would go through the VPN in order to reach you, it wouldn't matter at that point if you are behind a NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Usually NAT issues are going to be on your side i.e. your router/modem.
So make sure you port forward all the ports needed by that game (you will have to google or ask the company for the ports used). Hopefully its not your ISP and they are just mistaken or its being translated wrong.

To edit your router/modem you need to goto it's address in the browser Example: 192.168.1.1 or Comcast uses 10.1.10.1 sometimes. If your having issues getting the modem/router IP and you have a windows PC click the Start menu and type in "cmd" it should come up with either cmd.exe or Command Prompt open it and type in ipconfig their it should list 1 or more adapters, your looking for Default Gateway one of those will be the router/modem ip put that in the browser.

As for the login you might need to google your ISP modem and/or router but you can try admin/admin, cusadmin/highspeed, admin/password

Once logged in search for port forwarding and point those ports to the device or computer. You might need to reboot the modem/router for the settings to take.

If you have more then just one device between you and the internet like say you have comcast modem and you have your own router then things get even more complex for the solution.